# Use a different dataSource for quartz Scheduler that the one used in spring boot app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I am working on spring boot application with the Quartz Scheduler.

I have a application.properties and `quartz.properties` files where I configure my dataSource for each part.

I use a Configuration File to configure a `SchedulerFactoryBean` with the application context so I can use `@Autowired` annotation for my services in quartz Job. But the `Datasource` for the scheduler is the `spring.datasource` and not the `org.quartz.datasource` set in the quartz properties file for the scheduler

How can I set the `org.quartz.datasource` value only for my `SchedulerConfig` instead of the `spring.datasource` value ? or if it's not possible what would be the best practice to set up a different dataSource for my Quartz scheduler?

Thanks in advance

Code :

Application properties

```
# application.properties
    
spring.quartz.job-store-type=jdbc
spring.quartz.jdbc.initialize-schema=always

spring.datasource.url = jdbc:postgresql://databaseUrl
spring.datasource.username=myUsername
spring.datasource.password=myPassword
spring.datasource.driver-class-name.1=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.security.basic.enable=false
```

Quartz.properties

```
# Quartz.properties

org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = qrtz_
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = quartzDataSource
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDataSource.driver = org.postgresql.Driver
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDataSource.URL = jdbc:postgresql://QuartzDatabaseUrl
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDataSource.user = myUser
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDataSource.password = myPassword
org.quartz.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
org.quartz.scheduler.classLoadHelper.class=org.quartz.simpl.ThreadContextClassLoadHelper
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDataSource.provider = hikaricp
```

SchedulerConfig.java :

```java
// SchedulerConfig.java

@Configuration
public class SchedulerConfig {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    private QuartzProperties quartzProperties;


    @Bean
    public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean() {

        SchedulerJobFactory jobFactory = new SchedulerJobFactory();
        jobFactory.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.putAll(quartzProperties.getProperties());

        SchedulerFactoryBean factory = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
        factory.setOverwriteExistingJobs(true);
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factory.setQuartzProperties(properties);
        factory.setJobFactory(jobFactory);
        return factory;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are trying to outsmart the already available options. Spring Boot supports quartz out-of-the-box and [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.quartz) explains how to configure things to use a different datasource. Basically drop your own setup and let Spring BOot handle it.

Comment: Yes, that what I was doing first, but without the config file I can `@Autowired` service in Quartz Job so.

Comment: Sure you can. Your quartz jobs should be spring beans (as mentioned in the documentation).

Comment: Do you have some code example ? or Do I just need to add `@Bean` annotation to my quartz Job ?

Comment: Autowiring by setters works out-of-the-box you would need an extended `SpringBeanJobFactory` to enable `@Autowired` processing (I do recall creating an issue/pull request for that). ALthough it might be that that has been resolved. Your job would need to be a (prototype scoped) bean, so that it can use the metadata to autowire it when constructed by Quartz.